# How to capitalize the first letter of each word using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

From the URL http://www.example.com/alpha/beta
I need to return: Alpha,Beta

The following returns: alpha,beta

```
$(location).attr('href').split('/').slice(3, 5).join(',')
```

But I need the first letter of each of those words to be capitalized. 
Appreciate any advice!

Comment: depending on the use case you may also make use of the CSS function  `text-transform: capitalize;` which does exactly what you want just in CSS without any JS.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use too much jQuery, this should be done using standard JS :-)

```
$(location).attr('href').split('/').slice(3).map(function(s) {
    return s.charAt(0).toUppercase()+s.slice(1);
}).join(',')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var parts = $(location).attr('href').split('/').slice(3, 5);

$.each(parts, function (key, value) {
    parts[key] = value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
});

var result = parts.join(','); // 'Alpha,Beta'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(location).attr('href').split('/').slice(3).map(function(value) { return value.split('').map(function(value, at) { return (at > 0 ? value : value.toUpperCase()); }).join(''); }).toString()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also do it this way (here `replace()` will match only first letter without global switch in regex):

```js
var url='http://www.domain.com/alpha/beta';
var split=url.split('/');
var beta = split.pop();
var alfa = split.pop();
function capitalizeFirstLetter(str) {
  return str.replace(str.charAt(0), str.charAt(0).toUpperCase());  
};
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = capitalizeFirstLetter(alfa) + ',' + capitalizeFirstLetter(beta);
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```